# Why is charge $= nALe$?

Tags: charge, notation, density

Sorry if this question is a bit broad but I can't find any info on this by just searching.

The equation $q = neAL$ where $L$ is the length of a conductor, $A$ is the area of cross section, $n$ is the number of charges and $e$ is the fundamental charge. This equation clearly does not make sense from a dimensional point of view at first glance. So why is it true and why is it assumed true in most derivations for charge density in terms of drift velocity?

Comment: I think $n$ is meant to be the number of electrons per unit volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n$ is the particle density:  Number of particles per cubic meter in SI units.  $e$ would be the charge on a particle (Coulombs), here equal to the elementary charge (they could be protons).   With that I think that you will see the the dimensions are correct.

Comment: Thank you very much. Similar symbols for similar equations can be quite cumbersome to work with. @BySymmetry commented first so I upvoted his comment. I will mark this as the answer when the time limit is up.

Comment: A common convention is to use uppercase characters ($N$), for extrinsic properties (i.e., the _total_ number), and lowercase characters ($n$) for intrinsic properties (number per unit volume).  This way, $q = Ne$ is also valid, but less informative.

Answer (score -1):

It perfectly makes sense from the dimensional point of view because 'n' is the no of charges per unit volume

Answer (score -3):

$n$ is actually electron "density" (per unit volume). And $A\times l$ in the formula is nothing but volume. So that is why $Q = nALe$.